# Number of subnets in this network

Tags: subnet

Is it correct to say that there are 2 subnets in the network in the image below?

[image: http://i37.tinypic.com/2cwpy83.png]

Comment: there are 6 subnets here. not sure this question meets the rules...

Comment: Why are there 6 subnets?

Comment: assuming that these are all class C /24 networks there is: 223.1.1.X, 223.1.9.X, 223.1.7.X and so on

Comment: yh, that cleared it up, thanks for the links and responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might imply that there are multiple subnets from the diagram by the inclusion of routers which often indicate the boundry between two subnets, but they don't have to.  They would almost certainly indicate multiple broadcast domains.

All the IP addresses could belong to the 223.1.0.0/16 network.  Without knowing what subnet has been configured on each host you can't say for sure from the information given.

Answer (score 2):

6 subnets.

Once thing to note, is that some of the ip address doesn't make any sense. If this image is purely displaying subnets, then, the reason why there is six is because of the routers on the network. So if you count the amount of links between the routers and pc's you get **6.**

Comment: +1, you should not have any IP addresses ending in .0, and each segment is a subnet, even if only 2 addresses (rtouer-2-router 255.255.255.252)

Comment: so the amount of links determine how many subnets?

Comment: Not always, you can have physical failover links, but the number of logical links can be seen as number of subnets, if that makes sense.